# Как в приложении Android на RAD Studio (Delphi) запретить выключение экрана?

Tags: android, delphi, экран

Необходимо запретить выключение экрана смартфона при работе приложения Android. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Для наших целей используем WAKE_LOCK**

В манифест добавляем разрешение: *android.permission.WAKE_LOCK*

В модуле формы в секции *interface* подключаем модуль *Androidapi.JNI.Os.pas*:

```
Uses
  Androidapi.JNI.Os;
```

Объявляем переменную класса для хранения блокировки экрана:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  private
    FWakeLock: JPowerManager_WakeLock;
    ...
```

По событию показа формы вызываем код, чтобы установить блокировку:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  PowerObj: JObject;
  PowerManager: JPowerManager;
begin
  PowerObj := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService
    (TJContext.JavaClass.POWER_SERVICE);
  if Assigned(PowerObj) then
  begin
    PowerManager := TJPowerManager.Wrap((PowerObj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    if Assigned(PowerManager) then
    begin
      FWakeLock := PowerManager.newWakeLock
        (TJPowerManager.JavaClass.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK,
        StringToJString('Need to screen always on'));
      if Assigned(FWakeLock) then
      begin
        FWakeLock.acquire;
        Log('Screen WAKE_LOCK is ON');
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

По событию скрытия формы вызываем код, чтобы снять блокировку:

```
procedure TForm1.FormHide(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FWakeLock) then
  begin
    FWakeLock.release;
  end;
end;
```

Метод *newWakeLock* поддерживает несколько уровней WAKE_LOCK:

- PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK — гарантирует, что процессор работает, экран и
  подсветка клавиатуры могут выключиться;
- FULL_WAKE_LOCK — обеспечивает
  полную яркость экрана и подсветки клавиатуры (константа *deprecated* в
  API Level 17);
- SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK —
  экран включен, но может быть серым, подсветка клавиатуры может
  выключиться (константа *deprecated* в
  API Level 17);
- SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK — обеспечивает полную яркость
  экрана, а подсветка клавиатуры может выключиться (константа *deprecated* в
  API Level 13);

Также уровни *WAKE_LOCK* можно комбинировать с флагами:

- ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP — Включает экран, когда для *WAKE_LOCK* вызван метод *Acquire*;
- ON_AFTER_RELEASE — Когда для *WAKE_LOCK* вызван метод *Release*, включается таймер пользовательской активности, чтобы экран остался включенным немного дольше.

Answer (score 3):

Добавить в dpr:

```
Application.Initialize;
{$IF DEFINED(ANDROID)}
TAndroidHelper.Activity.getWindow.addFlags(TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); 
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Действительно, если из формы вызывать, приложение падает с ошибкой. Только в проекте получается флаги экрана менять.

Comment: Забыл указать что нужно подключить модули   Androidapi.Helpers,  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText и в Uses Permissions поставить Wack Lock = True

Comment: @Rusland воспользуйтесь функцией редактирования ответа - кнопка "править" внизу ;-)